# I am starting to explore Linq to SQL and this time i was trying to use the 'Contains' method and i have the following code written

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

The error message I am getting is:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

When I run the following code I get an error message saying that I need to explicitly specify the type of argument for method contains.

```
var result2 = from cltIntake in db.Client_Intakes
              where (from cltElig in db.Client_Eligibility_Referrals
                     where (
                            from cltDoctVerif in db.Doct_Verifications
                            where cltDoctVerif.Verification_Status == "Yes"
                            select cltElig.Asgnd_Caseworker_ID == 6
                            ).Contains(cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID)
                     select new { client_Eligibility_ID = cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID }
                    ).Contains(cltIntake.Client_Intake_ID)
                select new
                  {
                      cltInfo.First_Name,
                      cltInfo.Last_Name,

                  };
```

I have looked around a lot and tried to cast to type int, since the collection is type int, as follows

```
.Contains<Int32>(cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID)
```

but that threw an error saying:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

I really appreciate if someone gives me a solution for this. The thing is I don't really know much about IQueryable.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your selection is creating a sequence of anonymous types, but your call to Contains is passed a Int

So rather than `select new { client_Eligibility_ID = cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID }` just do `select cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID` additionally you have `select cltElig.Asgnd_Caseworker_ID == 6' which is projecting a boolean. You probably wanted`&& cltElig.Asgnd_Caseworker_ID == 6`

Additionally, consider simplifying the query

```
var result2 = from cltIntake in db.Client_Intakes
              from cltElig in db.Client_Eligibility_Referrals
              from cltDoctVerif in db.Doct_Verifications
              where cltDoctVerif.Verification_Status == "Yes"
                   && cltElig.Asgnd_Caseworker_ID == 6
                   && cltDoctVerif.Client_Eligibility_ID == 
                          cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID
                   && cltElig.Client_Eligibility_ID == 
                          cltIntake.Client_Intake_ID
            select new
              {
                  cltInfo.First_Name,
                  cltInfo.Last_Name,
              };
```

Comment: Hi Scott, i have tried your suggestion but still have the same error on the first contains, any idea why it still wants me to specify specific type argument?, thanks

Comment: I think I see it now `select cltElig.Asgnd_Caseworker_ID == 6'

Comment: Thank you so much Scott, you just got me out from the mess i was in, simplifying the query helped much !!!